# Count days for each month between two dates - postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to write a query which gives the number of days in each month between two specified dates.

**Example:**

date 1: 2018-01-01

date 2: 2018-05-23

**Expected Output:**

```
month      days
```

2018-01-01, 31

2018-02-01, 28

2018-03-01, 31

2018-04-01, 30

2018-05-01, 23

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `generate_series` and `group by date_trunc`

```
SELECT date_trunc('month',dt) AS month,
       COUNT(*) as days
FROM generate_series( DATE '2018-01-01',DATE '2018-05-23',interval '1 DAY' )
as dt group by date_trunc('month',dt) 
order by month;
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=09495aaa0ed08f5557e67e5219d256c6)